# How do you stop displaying error messages in React using React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am building a simple page where you can enter a Code and the Code is checked against a backend. If the code is invalid the backend returns an error with a Message like "Sorry the Code is invalid". The error is stored in a redux state, so the component can take it and display. But one problem I had, when the user navigates away and then back to the component, the error is still displayed because the state wasn't changed.

Currently my solution is to use an useEffect hook to check if the component is unmounted (that means the user navigated to another path) and trigger a resetError action, which sets the redux state 'error' to null. **But I wonder if this is the correct way or maybe there is a better/cleaner way?**

I am using React + React-Router + React-Redux + Redux-Saga + material ui

Here is my Code

```
function RegisterContainer({ errors, resetRegisterErrors}) {
    // Other stuff...

    useEffect(() => {
        return function cleanup() {
            resetRegisterErrors()
        }
    }, []);

    return <Register setCode={setCode} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} errors={errors} />;
}

const Register = ({ setCode, handleSubmit, errors }) => {
    return (
        <Container className={classes.root} maxWidth="sm">
            <ListErrors errors={errors}></ListErrors>
            <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <TextField variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    fullWidth
                    label="Code"
                    onChange={e => setCode(e.target.value)} />
                <Button type="submit"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submit}
                >
                    Register
                </Button>
            </form >
        </Container>)
}

// mapDispatchToProps, connect etc.
```

Comment: That's a fine way to do it. But you really should be asking yourself, why are you storing this in redux if it's tied to your component? The redux store tends to become a dumping ground for all things state related, even if the state isn't actually shared throughout the tree and is tied to just a subsection. In that case, you can just put the state in `useState` where it belongs, rather than throwing all things into the store just "because". Honestly, if this is your register component, then it's fine to keep all the "registering state" inside this component itself.

Comment: FYI, you're effect should have `resetRegisterErrors` as a dependency, even if it's just a wrapper function around dispatch, you should still use clean code: `useEffect(() => resetRegisterErrors, [resetRegisterErrors] )`

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your answer. The reason the state is in redux, is because I am using redux-saga to make an api call to the backend. Thus inside the saga a failure action is dispatched and a reducer updates the error state. I wouldn't know how to solve this problem.